# Умножение в php

Tags: php

Взять число число из score, умножить на 0.15? и обновить в intomoney, как?

Делал так:

```
UPDATE `a8531518_social`.`users_profiles` SET `intomoney` =
```

но дальше не знаю как.

Comment: Шо?

Вы не знаете как перемножить два числа?

И что за score такой? Что значит взять число из score. Где это? Что это?

Comment: ВЗЯТЬ ИЗ ТАБЛИЦЫ SCORE

Comment: @KryDos

Вот вот, даже до букваря дело не дошло, а уже япрограммист.

Comment: Все пытаются быть добрыми и отвечают на вопросы типа "как умножить два числа" до тех пор, пока не надоест. Мне надоело на третий раз.

Comment: А причём тут php? Вопрос-то вроде про sql (это разные языки).

Comment: @avp там ещё подчинённая таблица SCORE есть (а как она связана с изменяемой таблицей, ТС не разглашает).

Comment: @alexlz, это (SCORE) я вижу.

Просто подсказал ТС, что в гугле есть масса примеров SQL с update. Думаю, там и примеры со связанными таблицами есть.

Может посмотрит и догадается (хотя бы, как правильно переформулировать вопрос).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = $score * 0.15;
mysql_query("UPDATE a8531518_social.users_profiles SET intomoney =$result");
```

так наверное?